# serializationexception Visual C# into Unity\mono C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, mono

I've written a little UI for my mate to write dialogs in game. UI is making graph and binary serializes it into file. Deserialization should be implemented in unity, but unity sending a error. Is there any way to fix it? 
serialization:

```
Stream FileStream = File.Create("save");
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
serializer.Serialize(FileStream, graph);
FileStream.Close();
```

deserialization:

```
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream FileStream = File.OpenRead("save");
graph = (Graph)serializer.Deserialize(FileStream);
```

error:

> SerializationException: Could not find type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Dialogs.Node, WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Comment: Mono 2 used in Unity is not fully compatible with Microsoft .NET. Thus, it is impossible to do type based serialization from one side and deserialize on another.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Turned out Mono cannot deserialize binary serilized graph, but XML serialization solves the problem. I changed BinaryFormatter to Xml serializer and it perfectly deserialized in Mono.